# Решение ЗЛП графическим методом

Tags: алгоритм, математика

Нужно решить ЗЛП графичиским методом, а точнее написать программу по аналогии.

Задание:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При програмировании возникло несколько проблем:

После подставновки x1 и x2 некоторых значений мы получаем координаты 3 прямых + их направления.
Находим точки пересечения прямых.
Они и направления будут формировать ОДЗ.

После нужно провести градиент, в моем случае это будет (2;1) и от него искать максимум. Но как это сделать в 
программе ?

Comment: "Как найти пересечение двух прямых?" - решить систему из двух линейных уравнений с двумя неизвестными.

Comment: расшифруйте кто-нибудь ЗЛП и ОДЗ

Comment: @Grundy: ОДЗ — это, видимо, область допустимых значений, а вот что означает ЗЛП, у меня версий нет.

Comment: @VladD, у меня только Задача Линейного Программирования версия, но мне кажется она не совсем подходит

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Графический метод решения ЗЛП основан на построении выпуклого многоугольника (симплекса), полностью лежащего в первом квадранте. Начальным приближением является весь первый квадрант, т.е. треугольник с вершинами **(0,0), (Inf,0), (0, Inf),** где **Inf** - бесконечность, которую нужно "отрезать".

Идеальный вариант для "отрезания" - неравенство вида **ax<sub>1</sub> + bx<sub>2</sub> <= c, (a>0, b>0, c>0),** которое ликвидирует обе сингулярных вершины. В данном случае такого неравенства нет, но есть первое неравенство **(a<sub>1</sub>>0, c<sub>1</sub>>0),** и второе неравенство, которое после умножения на "-1" даёт **(b<sub>2</sub>>0, c<sub>2</sub>>0),** причём точка пересечения **M(x,y)** соответствующих им прямых лежит в первом квадранте. Это значит, что получен симплекс с вершинами **(0,0), (c<sub>1</sub>/a<sub>1</sub>,0), (x,y), (0,c<sub>2</sub>/a<sub>2</sub>).** Вершины следуют в циклическом порядке против часовой стрелки, в таком же порядке их следует хранить.

Каждое новое неравенство будет отрезать на симплексе группу смежных точек, которые ему не удовлетворяют, и заменять их на пару новых. Алгоритм несложен, если к каждой вершине привязать уравнения прямых, соединяющих её с предыдущей и последующей, и сохранять циклический порядок вершин.

Если известны все вершины симплекса, то максимум целевой функции достигается в одной из них. Начальную точку можно выбрать из соображений удобства реализации, направление обхода - в сторону возрастания целевой функции. При любом направлении обхода можно брать первый локальный максимум.