# Алгоритм поиска минимума в симплекс методе

Tags: алгоритм, математика

Мне нужно реализовать симплекс метод програмно.
Поиск максимума я уже сделал, нужен еще минимум. Как я понмаю алгоритм похож, но не могу понять некоторых моментов.

Когда я формирую матрицу для поиска максимума я фактически пишу в рядке F значения элементов x1,x2 * -1, как формировать эти значения при поиске минимума ?

Поиск "опорного" столбца производился по поиску минимального отрицательного в рядке F, а как искать опроный столбец для минимума ?

Задание со скриншота:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Поиск максимума:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Так, отвлеченно... Если вы ищете  минимум `F(X)` (`X` в данном случае вектор значений), то не совпадает ли он с максимумом `-F(X)`?

Comment: да, совпадет, но мне бы понять как правильно формировать матрицу, т.к. поиск происходит до тех пор пока есть отрицательные значения в рядке F и при моей реализации алгоритма если будет -2x1 -1x то данное решение будет считаться оптимальным.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение задачи линейного программирования симплекс-методом базируется на построении выпуклого многогранника (симплекса). Для случая двух переменных оно рассмотрено [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/633306/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%97%D0%9B%D0%9F-%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BC-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC/633584#633584), и при желании его можно обобщить на случай большего количества переменных.

Линейность задачи проявляется в следующем:
1. Все максимумы (и минимумы) задачи реализуются в вершинах симплекса.
2. Все максимумы (и минимумы) задачи достигаются в одной вершине или в группе смежных вершин, поэтому любой локальный максимум (и минимум) на симплексе является глобальным.

Думаю, что после посещения приведённой ссылки поиск минимума затруднений не вызовет.